# Error al rellenar celdas con excel4node, en el primer for funciona, pero si agrego otro se rompe

Tags: javascript, nodejs, funciones

El problema es que cuando duplico la línea para aplicarla a otras columnas dice que la función no existe... Alguna idea?

Si saco la función del ciclo `for` también deja de existir y ya no la puedo usar.

```
// Require library
var excel = require('excel4node');
var clase105 = require("./clase.json");

// Create a new instance of a Workbook class
var wbook = new excel.Workbook();

// Add Worksheets to the workbook
var wsheet = wbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

// Create a reusable style
var style = wbook.createStyle({
  font: {
    color: '#009900',
    size: 12,
  },
  numberFormat:0.0
});    

//alumnos
var { alumnos } = clase105;
var amarillo = 'F8F32B'
var rojo = 'CB3234'
var verde = '008F34'    

//imprimiendo cabeceras
wsheet.cell(1, 1).string('Nombre').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 2).string('Fecha de Nacimiento').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 3).string('Matematicas').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});

//comienzan las filas
var fila = 2;
var columna = 3;    

for (let i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
  //por cada alumno se imprime su nombre y la fecha de nacimiento
  var nombre = alumnos[i].nombre;
  var edad = alumnos[i].fechNac;

  var materias = alumnos[i].calificaciones;
  var materia = Object.keys(materias[0])      

  wsheet.cell(fila, 1).string(nombre).style(style);
  wsheet.cell(fila, 2).string(edad).style(style);

  for(let i= 0; i< materias.length; i++){
    var mates = materias[0].matematicas
    var espanol= materias[0].espanol
    var historia = materias[0].historia
    var literatura = materias[0].literatura

    var relleno = function(calif){

      if (calif < 5){
        relleno = rojo

      }else if(calif < 7){
        relleno = amarillo

      }else {
        relleno = verde
      }
      return relleno
    }            
    //por cada materia se imprime la calificacion
    wsheet.cell(fila,3).number(mates);
    wsheet.cell(fila,4).number(espanol).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: relleno(historia)}});
    wsheet.cell(fila,5).number(historia)
    //---AL AGREGAR ESTA LINEA DICE QUE LA FUNCION YA NO EXISTE, NO ENTIENDO POR QUE
    //.style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: relleno(historia)}});
    wsheet.cell(fila,6).number(literatura)    
  }
  fila++      
} 

for (let i = 0; i < materia.length; i++) {
  //se imprimen las materias que son incluidas para
  wsheet.cell(1, columna).string(materia[i]).style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
  console.log(materia[i])

  columna++
}

wbook.write('hojaDeCalculo.xlsx');
```

Cualquier otro comentario con respecto al código o las prácticas o lo que sea, es bien recibido. Este es el archivo JSON

```
{
"escuela":"Benito Juarez",
"salon":105,
"direccion":"Av Siempre Viva",
"alumnos":[
    {
        "nombre":"pepe",
        "apellido":"Hernandez",
        "nacimiento": "23/dic/89",
        "calificaciones":[
            {
                "matematicas":9,
                "espanol":5,
                "literatura":6,
                "historia":10
            }
        ],
        "fraces":[
            "hay tamales",
            "no me toques ahí",
            "como si fuera la primera vez"
        ]

    },
    {
        "nombre":"Joe",
        "apellido":"Lintz",
        "nacimiento": "12/may/89",
        "calificaciones":[
            {
                "matematicas":5,
                "espanol":10,
                "literatura":6,
                "historia":5
            }
        ],
        "fraces":[
            "es mi primer dia",
            "no siempre funciona",
            "odio tener siempre la razón"
        ]

    },
    {
        "nombre":"cristo",
        "apellido":"jesus",
        "nacimiento": "25/12/00",
        "calificaciones":[
            {
                "matematicas":9,
                "espanol":5,
                "literatura":7,
                "historia":9
            }
        ],
        "fraces":[
            "Yo pongo el pisto",
            "Que cruda me dio",
            "Ah te la creiste we XD"
        ]

    }
]
```

}

Comment: Hola, ¿sería posible que subas un ejemplo de tu archivo `clase.json`? Tal como tienes el código es bastante difícil entender el campo `materias`. Por otro lado, hay muchas cosas que podrías optimizar, pero necesito saber la estructura real de los documentos almacenados en el archivo `clase.json`. Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias, he agregado el archvio json, y por ahora, todos los archivos estan en la raiz de la misma carpeta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes varios detalles en la forma en la que tienes estructurado el código y la forma en la que intentas acceder a los valores almacenados en tu archivo `clase.json`.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea generar un libro de Excel usando la librería [`excel4node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node), usando [Node](https://nodejs.org/es/).

Los datos se almacenan en un archivo llamado `clase.json` y vienen (como su nombre indica) en formato JSON.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Suponiendo que usas la versión `6.4.0` o superior de Node, lo primero que haremos es usar `let` y `const` en lugar de `var`.

Esto es algo que repito mucho, si vas a importar una librería (usando `require` o `import`) hazlo sobre una variable *bindeada* como `const`, ya que no haremos modificaciones a la misma.

Así, la primera parte de tu código donde realizas las importaciones ha de quedar parecido a lo siguiente:

```
const xl = require('excel4node');
const clase105 = require('./clase.json');
```

Lo mismo haremos para declarar nuestro [`WorkBook`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node#workbook) y nuestra [`Worksheet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node#worksheet), pero en este caso usaremos `let`:

```
let wbook = new xl.Workbook();
let wsheet = wbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');
```

Ahora, según la estructura de nuestro archivo `clase.json`, podemos hacer lo siguiente para obtener los datos de los alumnos de dicho curso.

```
const alumnos = clase105.alumnos;
```

La función que devuelve un `string` para rellenar la celda con un color (rojo, amarillo o verde) la podemos refactorizar de la siguiente forma:

```
const fgColor = (calif) => {
  const rojo = 'CB3234';
  const amarillo = 'F8F32B';
  const verde = '008F34';
  return calif < 5 ? rojo : (calif < 7 ? amarillo : verde);
}
```

Como puedes apreciar, he movido las variables que contienen los valores (en `string`) de RGB dentro de la función. Además le he cambiado el nombre a la misma para que sea más claro al momento de su uso.

Ahora vamos a establecer la primera fila de nuestra hoja de Excel con las cabeceras requeridas:

```
wsheet.cell(1, 1).string('Nombre').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 2).string('Fecha de Nacimiento').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 3).string('Matematicas').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 4).string('Español').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 5).string('Literatura').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 6).string('Historia').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
```

Ahora debemos insertar los datos de los alumnos. Para eso vamos a usar el método [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) de los tipo `Array` de JavaScript.

Lo primero que establecemos es el valor de la fila en la que queremos insertar los datos. Como las cabeceras han sido insertadas en la primera fila, entonces los datos los insertaremos a partir de la segunda fila:

```
let currentRow = 2;
```

Ahora, usaremos el método `forEach()` para recorrer el `array` de alumnos, y por cada elemento del `array` escribiremos los valores adecuados en la celdas de nuestra hoja de trabajo:

```
alumnos.forEach((alumno, i) => {
  let nombre = alumno.nombre.concat(' ').concat(alumno.apellido);
  let calificaciones = alumno.calificaciones[0];
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 1).string(nombre).style(style);
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 2).string(alumno.nacimiento).style(style);
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 3).number(calificaciones.matematicas).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.matematicas)}});
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 4).number(calificaciones.espanol).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.espanol)}});
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 5).number(calificaciones.literatura).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.literatura)}});
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 6).number(calificaciones.historia).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.historia)}});
});
```

Por cada elemento del `array` se ejecuta la función anónima:

```
(alumno, i) => { ... }
```

La misma recibe 2 parámetros: `alumno` e `i`. El primero es claro, pero el segundo simplemente es una variable que contiene el índice del elemento que estamos iterando. Esto es muy útil para asignar la fila sobre la que escribiremos los datos en nuestra hoja de trabajo.

Las calificaciones de los alumnos se guardan en un campo de tipo `array`, en particular en el primer elemento de dicho `array`. Suponiendo que cada alumno posee calificaciones para las asignaturas especificadas en el documento (matemáticas, historia, literatura, español), asignaremos cada uno de sus valores a las celdas adecuadas. Hay que recordar que hemos establecido ya las cabeceras en la primera fila de la hoja de trabajo.

El nombre del alumno es la composición del campo nombre y del campo apellido, una forma de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

```
let nombre = alumno.nombre.concat(' ').concat(alumno.apellido);
```

Las calificaciones las guardamos así:

```
let calificaciones = alumno.calificaciones[0];
```

Para establecer el color de la celda de acuerdo al valor de la calificación hacemos lo siguiente:

```
wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 3).number(calificaciones.matematicas).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.matematicas)}});
```

Vemos que en el campo `fgColor` se llama a la función que hemos creado con anterioridad, la cual devolverá el valor adecuado según la calificación obtenida por el alumno.

Por último realizamos la escritura del archivo:

```
wbook.write('calificaciones.xlsx');
```

El código completo puede quedar así:

```
const xl = require('excel4node');
const clase105 = require('./clase.json');

let wbook = new xl.Workbook();
let wsheet = wbook.addWorksheet('Sheet 1');

// el estilo que deseamos darle a las celdas
const style = wbook.createStyle({
  font: {
    color: '#009900',
    size: 12
  },
  numberFormat: 0.0
});

// guardamos los datos de los alumnos
const alumnos = clase105.alumnos;

// función que devuelve un valor de acuerdo a la calificación
const fgColor = (calif) => {
  const rojo = 'CB3234';
  const amarillo = 'F8F32B';
  const verde = '008F34';
  return calif < 5 ? rojo : (calif < 7 ? amarillo : verde);
}

//imprimiendo cabeceras
wsheet.cell(1, 1).string('Nombre').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 2).string('Fecha de Nacimiento').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 3).string('Matematicas').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 4).string('Español').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 5).string('Literatura').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});
wsheet.cell(1, 6).string('Historia').style(style).style({font: {size: 14}});

// establecemos la fila sobre la que vamos a empezar a insertar datos
let currentRow = 2;

// recorremos el array de alumnos
alumnos.forEach((alumno, i) => {
  let nombre = alumno.nombre.concat(' ').concat(alumno.apellido);
  let calificaciones = alumno.calificaciones[0];
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 1).string(nombre).style(style);
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 2).string(alumno.nacimiento).style(style);
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 3).number(calificaciones.matematicas).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.matematicas)}});
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 4).number(calificaciones.espanol).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.espanol)}});
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 5).number(calificaciones.literatura).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.literatura)}});
  wsheet.cell(currentRow + i, 6).number(calificaciones.historia).style({fill:{ type: 'pattern',patternType: 'solid',fgColor: fgColor(calificaciones.historia)}});
});

//escribimos el libro
wbook.write('calificaciones.xlsx');
```

Una captura del resultado, usando los valores proporcionados en la pregunta:

[image: Captura del resultado]

Espero que esto aclare tus dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: muy bueno, estoy trabajando en ello. Gracias